# Validity, Utility and Cost of Clinical Tests

Tags: data-request, medical

[Medical tests are characterized by validity, utility and cost](http://www.genome.gov/10001733):

- **Validity** is the probability that the test results are correct.
- **Utility** is the usefulness of having correct results (e.g. how much life can be gained by taking a test, finding out that there is a disease, and treating it in time).
- **Cost** is, simply, the cost of taking the test.

I am looking for tables which show the validity, utility and cost of some commonly used clinical tests.

I don't need them for clinical use; I only intend to bring some examples to illustrate a theoretical paper about diagnostics. So, the tables don't have to be very accurate or up-to-date.

I found several research papers that try to assess the validity and utility of novel tests, e.g. some genetic or molecular tests for cancer, but they are too difficult for me because I don't have sufficient background in genetics or molecular biology. I need a simpler and more approximate table.