# Commercial Medical Diagnostic testing Precision and Accuracy

Tags: medical

Since the accuracy and precision (repeatability) of a test is relevant to any decision; how do I find (or phrase) search's to find data on this for commercial clinics?
I used to work for an animal diagnostic company and they continually evaluated their accredited testing facilities; so I am sure that human diagnostic testing facilitates must have records and audits by *somebody*.

This a rephrase of [Validity, Utility and Cost of Clinical Tests](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/5355/validity-utility-and-cost-of-clinical-tests)

Answer (score 1):

Sensitivity, Specificity, Positive Predictive Value, and Negative Predictive Value are used in medicine and public health to evaluate the accuracy of diagnosing patients with a certain disease or injury.

For instance, you might often come across journal articles which evaluate whether an ICD9 diagnosis of Severe Sepsis is accurate for a sample of patients by comparing the diagnosis with actual clinical charts and bio-markers.

This [page](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat507/node/71) offers an excellent general explanation as to what they mean and how they are used in research

Comment: Thank you for the link; but I really wanted data on the repeatability/accuracy of routine testing at a commercial lab.  For instance Leukocytes, Cholesterol, etc ...  I have a wife who is getting transfusions every 2 weeks (more or less) based upon a measure of her active red blood cells.  The doctors order the transfusion based upon the threshold and I want to know things like how likely it is that the transfusion order is late or premature because of lab error.  We all make mistakes.  I am also close to thresholds for glucose and want to know the chances of a false positive due to lab error.